# steroids android build is too much heavy

Tags: steroids

I created a new app with steroids. literally deployed and built it for android. but when I downloaded my app, it was roughly 7mbs.

Why is that so much large file? is there any way to reduce it?

**-note: I didn't add any extra files to my application. just steroids default starting template.**

Comment: You need to provide other statistics, like what the app size is without steroids, or what the app does.   Please be more specific and consider making your question clearer.

Comment: steroids is sort of a platform, not a pluggable piece, if I wanted to develop my application using native android sdk it would be less than 100k for sure. the question is, should I expect steroid's apps to be naturally more than 7mb or not?

Comment: I think this is rather normal for Steroids builds. Don't forget that you are packaging Cordova's and Steroids' javascript-to-native bridges, app icons/splash screens, potentially Cordova plugins if you are using any, plus your own app scripts and assets. I have three app build with Steroids and they all are around 7 to 8 mbs